# Binding socket to network 332 failed: EPERM

Tags: android, sockets, retrofit2, android-networking, wifimanager

In one of our android app while trying to connect to server using https, it is throwing me error saying,

network capability changed: [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_METERED&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED LinkUpBandwidth>=12000Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=30000Kbps TransportInfo: <SSID: , BSSID: 02:00:00:00:00:00, MAC: 02:00:00:00:00:00, Security type: 0, Supplicant state: COMPLETED, Wi-Fi standard: 4, RSSI: -40, Link speed: 6Mbps, Tx Link speed: 6Mbps, Max Supported Tx Link speed: 150Mbps, Rx Link speed: 6Mbps, Max Supported Rx Link speed: 150Mbps, Frequency: 2412MHz, Net ID: -1, Metered hint: false, score: 0, CarrierMerged: false, SubscriptionId: -1, IsPrimary: -1> SignalStrength: -40 RequestorUid: 10427 RequestorPkg:

scanSSIDs ::Error while searching SSID ... .

The application connects to

If i restart the application, it is working properly.
I think app is storing some network cache, anyone know hoe to clear this ?